# manipulating string in c

Tags: c, string, token, tokenize

I am trying to take a string input from user and then reverse only the words starting with a vowel.Then reprint the changed string.I have used the strtok() function to separate the words from the string.But reversing the words,seems to be a problem....I have written a code for this program,but it is having runtime error.So,it will be really useful,if anyone could help me correct my code or provide me with a solution.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *tok);
int length(char *t);
int main()
{
  char sen[50];
  const char s[2] = " ";
  int i;
  printf("Enter a Sentence: ");
  gets(sen);

  char *token;
  token = strtok(sen, s);
  printf("Output: ");

  while (token != 0)
  {
    char z[20] =
    { *token };
    for (i = 0;; i++)
    {
      if (z[i] == ' ')
      {
        z[i] = '\0';
        break;
      }
    }
    if (z[0] == 'a' || z[0] == 'A' || z[0] == 'e' || z[0] == 'E' || z[0] == 'i'
        || z[0] == 'I' || z[0] == 'o' || z[0] == 'O' || z[0] == 'u'
        || z[0] == 'U')
    {
      reverse(token);
    }
    else
      printf("%s ", *token);

    token = strtok(NULL, s);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

//function for reversing the particular parts of string
void reverse(char *tok)
{
  char x[20] =
  { *tok };
  int i, j, len;
  char temp;

  for (i = 0;; i++)
  {
    if (x[i] == ' ')
    {
      x[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
  len = length(tok);

  j = len - 1;
  for (i = 0; x[i] != len / 2; i++)
  {
    temp = x[i];
    x[i] = x[j];
    x[j] = temp;
    j--;
  }
  printf("%s", x);
  printf(" ");
}

//function for determining the length of the token string
int length(char *t)
{
  int i = 0;
  char y[20] =
  { *t };
  for (;; i++)
  {
    if (y[i] == ' ')
    {
      y[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }

  while (y[i] == '\0')
  {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? And what error?

Comment: I am getting the error after inputting a string.After input,the program just stops working.I can't figure out where the error is..

Comment: Note that `printf("%s",x);
printf(" ");` can be abbreviated to `printf("%s ", x);`.

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: If your program ever fails with a runtime error (or segmentation fault), you should never spend too much time looking for it in the code. Instead, use a debugger to get a stack trace and line number (Visual Studio debugger on windows or gdb on unix). That way you can usually get a much better idea about where the error is.

Comment: What are those loops `for (i = 0;; i++)` meant for? Did you try the program without them?

Comment: And what is this `x[i] != len / 2;` for?

Comment: To get the length of `0`-terminated `char`-array, a C-"string" use `strlen()`.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
printf("%s ", *token);
```

passes a `char` where a `0`-terminated  `char[]` is expected.

The lesson learned is: **Always compile with all warnings on!** (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc)

Comment: changed that to **printf("%s ",z);**
still not working..having runtime error after getting input

Comment: Also please see *Rikayan Bandyopadhyay*'s answer. @AsifulNobel

Comment: Also consider using a debugger, to step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in this line:

```
if(z[i]==' ')
```

You've split with the token `' '`, so that means there is no `' '` in `z[]`. So the loop never ends.

Comment: but I have stored the token in an array z[],so i put the if condition to manually put a null pointer at the end of the string in z[].I have also put **break** condition to stop the loop,after assigning the null pointer.Then why won't the loop end??

Comment: @Asiful How will you know when the array ends if there is no null pointer? Also there is no space in z[]. So the loop will never end.

Comment: ok,I have understood it now.....but then how can I solve this problem?Because without null pointer,most of my code is not gonna function...

Comment: Same issue for `x[]` in `reverse()`.

Comment: @Asiful keep the count using strlen. And loop that much. Then add the null character.

Comment: @alk Actually quite a few bugs in the code

Comment: after doing all this,I am just getting output of the first character of token word...I guess it is happening because,I have initialized the z array with only the first element of the word,that the pointer is referring to...how do I get the whole word stored in **z[ ]** using the pointer ***token**??

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *tok);
int length(char *t);

int main(){
    char sen[50];
    const char s[2] = " ";

    printf("Enter a Sentence: ");
    scanf("%49[^\n]", sen);//gets(sen); //"gets" : Obsolete !

    char *token = strtok(sen, s);

    printf("Output: ");

    while (token != NULL){
        char z = *token;
        if (z == 'A' || z == 'E' || z == 'I' || z == 'O' || z == 'U' ||
            z == 'a' || z == 'e' || z == 'i' || z == 'o' || z == 'u'){
            reverse(token);//print by this function
        } else {
            printf("%s ", token);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *tok){//original not change
    int i, len = length(tok);
    char x[len + 1];

    for (i = 0; i<len; ++i){
        x[i] = tok[len-i-1];
    }
    x[i]='\0';
    printf("%s ", x);
}

int length(char *t){//use strlen
    int i;
    for(i=0;*t;++i, ++t)
        ;
    return i;
}
```